# Changing color in Switchify Api of Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working with the **switchify api** of **jquery** found here....[Link](http://rawnet.github.com/jquery-switch/)

I am successfully implemented the code but I have just one concern where can I change the background color of **on** and **off** positions.
As here you can see the **on** position is green and **off** position is in white color(some shade of white :) ).I want to change the color of the **off** position to **green**, **red** , **blue** or anything..Please shed some light...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you have css file name jquery.switch.css their you can edit and specify your color you want like this

```
.ui-switch-on{
   background: green;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
   border-color: #006600;
   border-right: medium none #006600;
   border-top-right-radius: 0;
   padding-right: 20px;
}
.ui-switch-off{
   background:yellow;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
   border-color: #660000;
   border-left: medium none #660000;
   border-top-left-radius: 0;
   padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: the problem is I have many switches and have to specify different color for different switches....

Answer (score 1):

Check with firebug there are two classes .**ui-switch-on** & .**ui-switch-off** on it. Just override with your styling. For example write like this:

```
.ui-switch-on{
    background:red !important;
}
.ui-switch-off{
    background:yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: the problem is I have many switches and have to specify different color for different switches